# Инструмент/Framework для генерации A4 листа(сертификата об обучении) заполняющий данные введенные пользователем

Tags: ios, swift

Подскажите инструменты для интеграции с мобильным приложением, который возьмет на себя генерацию файла формата A4 (заполняющий данными введенными пользователем) для дальнейшей отправки на емейл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFKit в iOS который позволяет генерить готовые PDF документы